# How to rotate also the body when the player is looking at the target if the player is moving the opposite direction from the target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAt;
    public Vector3 defaultFacing;
    public float angleLimit = 60f;
    public float rotationDamping = 3f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Using late update so animations don't overwrite my transform manipulations...
    void LateUpdate()
    {

        // For this example i'll be using the root objects forward vector as what i want to be my reference constraint vector.
        // You might want to use something else though.
        defaultFacing = transform.root.forward;

        // The direction from this transform, pointing at the look at target.
        Vector3 directionToLookAtTarget = lookAt.position - transform.position;

        float angle = Vector3.Angle(directionToLookAtTarget, defaultFacing);

        // Since i'm just using the root objects forward vector as a constraint, i can just use its rotation as my default rotation instead of calculation a Quaternion.LookAt.
        Quaternion defaultRotation = transform.root.rotation;
        // The look at rotation to the target if it were completely unrestrained.
        Quaternion lookAtCompleteRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToLookAtTarget);

        Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        // If the angle is greater than our limit, return a rotation that is in the direction of the lookAtCompleteRotation but is limited to the angle we chose as a limit.
        // Otherwise, if its within our limit, we just return the rotation as is.
        if (angle > angleLimit)
            finalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.forward);
        //finalRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(defaultRotation, lookAtCompleteRotation, angleLimit / angle);
        else
            finalRotation = lookAtCompleteRotation;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, finalRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);

    }
}
```

The script is attached to the character neck in the rig. So when running the game and the player is standing still if I'm moving the target(lookAt) around the player head will look at the target.

The problem is when the target is stay still and I'm moving the player so if I'm moving the player to another direction away from the target the player neck(head) is still rotating looking at the target but the body is facing the way it's moving so the head is looking at the target and the body is facing the moving direction.

I think the logic should be if I'm moving the player to some direction the head should be looking forward facing the moving direction and only if the player is moving to view area direction of the target then look at the target again.

but I'm not sure how to do it.  How to make that the neck will face the direction it's moving and only when moving to the area of the target then look at the target.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Bool function that returns true only if the player is able to see the enemy. The way you can do this is :

1. an if with a Physics.Raycast between player and enemy. Of course if this is true you can also return true from the function
2. in the same function you can use a variable of the angle you want to see and create 2 variables. One is tha angle multiplyed for a value less than 1 (0.5 for example) and one for a value bigger than 1 (1.5) and then check form the start angle to the last one with the RayCast and see if it hits the enemy. Of course. If you hit the enemy you should return true